# import owl.carousel from webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, carousel, frontend

I am new to the F2E world.
I just created a web application using create-react-app. (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

I wanted to import owl.carousel into my projects, so that I followed the guide of NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/owl.carousel) ,which of the syntax is:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'imports?jQuery=jquery!owl.carousel';
```

but the debugger console indicated the error :

```
Unexpected '!' in 'imports?jQuery=jquery!owl.carousel'. Do not use      import syntax to configure webpack loaders import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
```

I tried another syntax:

```
import owlCarousel from 'owl.carousel'
```

and the error would be:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

Could somebody help me figure out what happened? thanks.

Update:  my webpack loader settings:

```
loaders: [
  // Process JS with Babel.
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: findCacheDir({
        name: 'react-scripts'
      })
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'file',
    query: {
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }
  }
]
```

my component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './css/style.css';
import './css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/owl.carousel.css';
import FruitSelector from './containers/fruit_Selector';
import FruitDetail  from './containers/fruit_Detail';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'owl.carousel';

class App extends Component {
render() {
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".content-slider").owlCarousel({
      slideSpeed: 350,
      singleItem: true,
      autoHeight: true,
      navigation: true,
      navigationText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"]
  });
});

return (
  <div className="App">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
      <FruitSelector/>
    </div>
    <div className="col col-md-8">
        <FruitDetail/>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

my webpack.config.dev.js plugin setting:

```
plugins: [

new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
  PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl
}),

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  template: paths.appHtml,
}),
new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
// Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
// a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
// See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
// If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
// to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
// makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
// See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
  })]
```

the error pops out:

```
App.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).owlCarousel is not a function(…)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Remove plugin which blocks import syntax

Problem is with import syntax which is not default webpack syntax. You have installed in Your project https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-webpack-loader-syntax.md to block it, for sure it is part of react-create-app. Please remove it to enable this syntax.

**Owl.carousel** needs `jQuery` library imported inside it because it uses **$** variable, so this is problem and it is why `webpack-loader-syntax` must be removed.

If we try to import `owl` in standard way then `jQuery` is not defined there ( every file in webpack has own scope ), so it will throw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

---

### ( Alternative )Use shimming module

If removing plugin is problem then You can try to add jQuery to every module with usage it as shimming module - https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html.

In webpack config it will look like:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
]
//other config vars
};
```

And just add it by:

```
import 'owl.carousel'
```

Comment: thanks, but how could I define jQuery or $ before the owl? I've installed the package  'imports-loader' but still the same error.

Comment: Check my update answer problem is that You have this https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-webpack-loader-syntax.md installed and it blocks the syntax, so standard webpack would work, You project has plugin to block it.

Comment: @AirNoir check my edited answer with shimming module solution

Comment: it works after I set the webpack.ProviderPlugin with "window.jQuery" : "jquery" , thank you so much !  :)

Comment: I got new problem ... owlCarousel is not a function,  seems that it's failed to load the owl.carousel library.   :(

Comment: Try to remove import jquery ( it should be imported everywhere )

Comment: If I remove import jQuery,  there would be an error of "$ is not defined".

Comment: You tried that? This plugin adds jquery to every module, so try to remove the line.

Comment: I removed the eslint loader and then removed the import $ now. The undefined error disappeared, but I still get the error of "owlCarousel is not a function" :((( I am crazy now..

Comment: I will try to back to this problem later, i must check this in real code.

Comment: I thought I found the problem.  I use "npm install owl.carouse" instead of  "yarn add owl.carouse" .. and then it works..I really don't know why. I really appreciate for your time. thanks , you are a great guy :)))

Comment: @Maciej Sikora What does import 'owl.carousel' do?  Does it need a special webpack loader for it to work?

Comment: If you need `webpack.ProvidePlugin`, consider using `expose-loader` instead.
It worked in my case and exposes variables outside the webpack bundle, too.

Answer (score 4):

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery')),
            jQuery: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery')),
            'window.jQuery': path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery')),
        }),
```

**It helped me**

because the carousel has its own modules(`node_modules/owl.carousel/node_modules/jquery`) and the plugin takes from there jQuery and  writes the carousel in to this module

Comment: Thanks, it helped me too. I had `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({'window.jQuery': 'jquery'});` but it wasn't working until I used path.resolve.

Answer (score 1):

```
 dont import jquery as (import $ from 'jquery') as owl.carousel need jquery, instead in webpack.config file :
    const webpack = require("webpack");
    .....
    
    
    ----------
    
    module.exports={
    plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
    ]
}
    
    this works perfectly alright.
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

I had a issue with same error "Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined", but making sure the Jquery reference was first, fixed it for me.

```
<!-- Webjar References -->
  <script src="webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
```