# How to import jquery extension in webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, webpack, owl-carousel

I am trying to import owl.carousel module.

Method as:

```
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'imports?jQuery=jquery!owl.carousel';
```

from official documentation makes webpack return error:

```
ERROR in ./main/templates/default/assets/js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'imports' in 
'/var/www/digits/main/templates/default/assets/js'
 @ ./main/templates/default/assets/js/index.js 6:0-44
```

while frontend compilation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483488/4475605

Comment: I have another problem, my code does not compiling at all, unlike this.