# Codesandbox Error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')"

Tags: reactjs, package.json, owl-carousel, codesandbox

I'm trying to import react-owl-carousel in my project. I see the error mentioning, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')". Although I've properly installed owlCarousel.
Here is my "App.js":

```
import React from "react";
import OwlCarouselDemo from "./OwlCarouselDemo";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Owl Carousel Demo</h1>
      <OwlCarouselDemo />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is "OwlCarouseldemo.js":

```
import React from "react";
import OwlCarousel from "react-owl-carousel";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";

const items = [
  { id: 1, text: "Slide 1" },
  { id: 2, text: "Slide 2" },
  { id: 3, text: "Slide 3" },
  { id: 4, text: "Slide 4" },
  { id: 5, text: "Slide 5" }
];

const OwlCarouselDemo = () => {
  return (
    <OwlCarousel className="owl-theme" loop margin={10} items={3}>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div className="item" key={item.id}>
          <h3>{item.text}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </OwlCarousel>
  );
};

export default OwlCarouselDemo;
```

And this is "package.json":

```
{
  "name": "owlcarousel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "loader-utils": "3.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-owl-carousel": "2.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

And here is the codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/owlcarousel-w37y5v?file=/src/OwlCarouselDemo.js:0-652

Comment: Hey, you can refer to this answer and the one below it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483488/19119712 You can also take directions for implementation from the comments. Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import owl.carousel from webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483358/import-owl-carousel-from-webpack)

Comment: Have you viewed my codesandbox? I didn't import anything, just installed simply from codesadbox's "Add dependency" tab.

Comment: Hey, I get it. I still think you should take a look at everything mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483488/19119712 Seems like the person answering has also dealt with the problem you are facing, i.e., "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined" (which, the last time I checked, your sandbox console displayed).